# Only print input lines longer than 10 characters (ANSI C)

Tags: c, string, file-io, input, output

So I'm writing a practice program in C which has the purpose of taking user input and then after EOF is reached, it reads back the input but only lines that were longer than 10 characters.

I am on Linux, so EOF is Ctrl + D, but, if an input line is longer than 10, it prints when I push enter, rather than waiting until EOF is reached.

here is my code:

```
#define MAXSIZE 1000
#define SIZE 10

int checklen(char line[], int index);

int main()
{
    char currentline[MAXSIZE];
    int i = 0;

        while ((currentline[i] = getchar()) != EOF){
            if (currentline[i] == '\n'){
                if (checklen(currentline, i) > SIZE){
                    printf("%s", currentline);
                }
            }
            ++i;
        }

    return 0;
}

int checklen(char line[], int index)
{
    int i;
        for (i=index; line[i] != '\n'; ++i){
            ;
        }
    return i;
}
```

EDIT: I have been trying to figure it out for quite a while now with no luck.  I'm not really understanding what you guys are saying and everything but we'll get there eventually :)

I have since rewritten the code but it is still not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000
#define SIZE 10

void examine(char input[], int index);

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char input[MAX];
    char output[MAX];

        //take user input and store it in our input string
        while ((input[i] = getchar()) != EOF){
            ++i;
        }

        //put a null byte at the end of input[]
        input[i+1] = '\0';

        //examine line by line until end of string (null byte)
        for (i=0; input[i] != '\0'; ++i){
            if (input[i] == '\n'){
                examine(input, i);
            }
        }

    return 0;
}

void examine(char input[], int index)
{
    //decrement through input[] until \n or start [0] is reached
    int i=0;

        for (i=0; ((input[index] != '\n') || (index > 0)); ++i){
            --index;
        }
    //if line is bigger than 10 chars, print it 
    if (i>SIZE){
        for (; input[index+1] != '\n'; ++index){
            putchar(input[index]);
        }
    }

    //otherwise, return

    return;
}
```

Comment: just realised it is because my printf is inside the if statement.  Now i just gotta find a way around it...

Comment: `EOF` is not a `char`, it's an `int`!

Comment: If you really don't want any output to appear until after the input is complete, you are going to have to save each valid (long enough) line when you encounter the newline, and then after the reading loop, you'll have to scan through the list of saved lines.  Generating the output as you go is much simpler, and more economical of memory.

Comment: Your `checkline()` code is wrong too. You only call it when `currentline[i]` is newline; inside the function, therefore, you set `i` to `index`, the loop condition immediately fails, so you return `index` which you knew in the first place.  Your condition in the calling code could be `i > SIZE`.  Also, beware: you do not have null terminated strings.  This will wreak havoc sooner or later.

Comment: This question is unclear, you're trying to either print or only accept input (it's unclear which) of lines more than `SIZE` chars long, but in your code, it looks like you only want to print all the lines you've received (regardless of size) if you have more than `SIZE` lines. Please clarify.

Comment: They wish to display all lines that have 10 characters or more, ignoring shorter lines - displaying the results in a "batch", only after EOF has been reached - by storing each qualifying line in some kind of buffer/array to be displayed at the end (sequentially processing line by line until EOF is reached).

Comment: One way would be to store the index before the end of the outer while loop. So if the newly-stored line's size is less than 10, then rewrite i with the stored index, so the next line would overwrite this line. This is a way to prevent using 2-d arrays

Comment: What's wrong with using sprintf as it is iterating along, and display the results that qualified at the end of the loop? The OP is suggesting that this is a classroom example, so I am certain it does not have to be run up in a production environment.

Comment: That would require the use of another buffer array :p

Answer (score 1):

rewrote it. was actually really easy. here is the code:

```
/*this program takes keyboard input from the user until EOF
and prints out their input excluding lines less than or equal to LINESIZE*/

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 2000
#define LINESIZE 10

void checkprint(char line[]);

int main()
{
    char input[MAX];
    char line[MAX];
    int i, i2;
    i2 = 0;

        //take input until EOF (Ctrl + D)
        for (i=0; (input[i]=getchar()) != EOF; ++i){
            ;
        }

    //add null byte to end of string    
    input[i+1] = '\0';
    //basic formatting for aesthetics
    putchar('\n');


        //copy a line into line[] from input[] until NULL byte reached
        for (i=0; input[i] != '\0'; ++i){
            line[i2] = input[i];
            ++i2;
            //if end of line, call checkprint
            if (input[i] == '\n'){
                checkprint(line);
                i2=0;
            }
        }   

    return 0;
}

void checkprint(char line[])
{


    int i;
        //find the length of the line
        for (i=0; line[i] != '\n'; ++i){
            ;
        }

        //if longer than LINESIZE, print it
    if (i > LINESIZE){
        putchar('\n');
        for (i=0; line[i] != '\n'; ++i){
            putchar(line[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000
#define SIZE 10

void examine(char input[], int index);

int main(void){
    char input[MAX];
//  char output[MAX];
    int i, ch;

    for(i=0; i< MAX - 1 && (ch = getchar()) != EOF; ++i)
        input[i] = ch;

    input[i] = '\0';

    for (i=0; input[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        if (input[i] == '\n'){
            examine(input, i);
        }
    }
    examine(input, i);//for '\0'

    return 0;
}

void examine(char input[], int index){
    int i;

    if(index == 0) return ;

    for (i=1; index - i >= 0 && input[index-i] != '\n'; ++i)
        ;

    --i;
    if (i > SIZE){
        while(i>0)
            putchar(input[index - i--]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return;
}
```

---

buffer's size 11 version.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

void print(char ch){
    static char buf[SIZE+1];
    static index = 0, over = 0;
    int i;

    if(over){
        putchar(ch);
        if(ch == '\n')
            over = 0;
        return ;
    }
    if(ch == '\n'){
        index = 0;
    } else {
        buf[index++] = ch;
        if(index == SIZE + 1){
            for(i=0;i<index;++i){
                putchar(buf[i]);
            }
            index = 0;
            over = 1;
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    int ch;

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
        print(ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
//simple is to use the fgets
```

Comment: I feel like enough if there is a buffer of 11 characters will be.